# Unable to catch the response from the api call

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to perform slider using AngularJS.

I have written as below for HTML.

[HTML]

```
<input type="range" ng-model="project_data.project_evaluation_rate" min=0 max=100 step="0.5">
<code>{{project_data.project_evaluation_rate}}</code> // It is bound to the ng-model!
```

Yes, the ng-model and the {{project_data.project_evaluation_rate}} is bound and it works!

However, the console.log below does not work.

[controller.js]

```
$http.post("../crud/projects_insert.php", {
  project_evaluation_rate : $scope.project_data.project_evaluation_rate
    })
  .then(function(){
    console.log(project_evaluation_rate);
  });
```

I don't know why that console.log is not bound. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: does your api get invoked

Comment: How can I verify that the API is invoked?

Comment: check your network tab

Comment: chrome developer tools should have the request and the response

Comment: *I don't know why that console.log is not bound.*: what does that mean? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Where is this project_evaluation_rate variable that you're printing defined?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, I thought it was more like.. missing of "onchange or ng-change".. of which I am not sure.. Wouldn't the data from HTML be sending to the Controller.JS using onchange?

Comment: Please answer the questions.

Comment: post the code which calls onchange

Comment: Clearly your api is either not responding or sending an error code. Please verify whether your api is working or not.

Comment: @JB Nizet, when I run console.log(project_evaluation_rate); it should appear in JAVA SCRIPT CONSOLE. But it doesn't. I expect to have project_evaluation_rate to have what $scope.project_data.project_evaluation_rate is representing.. I mean, If I do console.log($scope.project_data.project_evaluation_rate); then it works. but if I have console.log(project_evaluation_rate), then it says it is NOT DEFINED.

Comment: @Sajeetharan, I was lost doing onchange.. I removed it realizing that it would still work without onchange.

Comment: OK, so the http post succeeds, and then you're printing a variable that you haven't defined anywhere, and it prints undefined. Nothing surprising to me. Why do you think that a variable you've never defined should be defined? Oh, and no need to shout.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I see what you mean. So I had put $scope.project_evaluation_rate = {}; up there. may this is the way to define the variable?

Comment: $scope.project_evaluation_rate is not the same thing as project_evaluation_rate, and is not the same thing as $scope.project_data.project_evaluation_rate. What are you trying to print? What you submitted? What the http response contains? What the value selected in the range contains?

Comment: THANK YOU ALL FOR ASSISTING ME! @JB Nizet, I understood the concept you explained to me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this ?

```
$http.post("../crud/projects_insert.php", {
  project_evaluation_rate : $scope.project_data.project_evaluation_rate
    })
  .then(function(project_evaluation_rate){ // this is the place where data should come
    console.log(project_evaluation_rate);
  });
```

Comment: It worked! I didn't know that it would work that way! I really thank you! :)

Comment: Cool. Can you please upvote and accept it as answer?

Comment: Happy coding :)